# Paging data tables in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables, paging

I have a table with more the fifty records in it. I want to display them in pages of five records per page. My current approach uses jquery datatables, as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var length = $('#data-datatable tbody tr').length;
    $('#data-datatable').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" : 5,
        "iTotalRecords":   length
    });
});
```

This shows all fifty records in one page! How can I get the display I want please?

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: All fifty records are shown in single page i want to show 5 records per page but it generates only single  page.

Comment: You should really just update your question with that information, the more you elaborate, the more likely you are to receive good help.

Comment: Can you please add html  content?

Comment: Rewrote to make it clear what would constitute a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumptions with your question:

1. You have a html-table, that is being populated from the context having all 50 rows.
2. Now you want to do pagination for those elements.

Here, I'm going to show some approaches:

1. Think about [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/) . You context variable will do the pagination.
2. Use [Django-datatable-view](http://django-datatable-view.appspot.com/) . It directly works with jquery-datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these two lines:

```
"iTotalDisplayRecords" : 5,
"iTotalRecords":   length
```

Try this one line instead:

```
"pageLength": 5,
```

More here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Also, in order to actually see the paging buttons, you'll need to add this:

```
"dom": '<"top">t<"bottom">p<"clear">',
```