# Datatable (server-side pagination) showing only two pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

As per the title, 
my datatable shows only the first two pages of results. 
Editing the value in iDisplayLength results in more or less records being displayed in a single page but doesn't change the fact that the datatable shows only the first two pages...

This is the initialization of the datatable:

```
var datatable = datatableElement.DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "searching": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true, 
            "iDisplayLength": 20, 
            "lengthChange": false,
            "stateSave": false,
            "aaSorting": [0, 'desc'],  
            "pagingType": "simple",
            "info": false,
            "columnDefs": [
                {"orderable": false, "targets": [1, 2]}
            ],
            "ajax": {
                "url": siteData.ajaxurl,
                "type": 'POST',
                "data": function(data){
                    data.action = "transactions_history";
                    data.startDate = transactionStartDate.val();
                    data.endDate = transactionEndDate.val();
                    data.type = transactionType.val();
                }
            },
            "language": {
                "url": siteData.ajaxurl + "?action=datatable_internazionalization"
            }
        });
```

And this is the ajax function:

```
public static function ajax_transactions_history()
{
    $start = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'start') ?: 0;
    $length = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'length') ?: 20; 
    $draw = intval(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'draw'));
    $startDate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'startDate') ?: '1/1/2010';
    $endDate = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'endDate') ?: date("n/j/Y");
    $type = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type');
    $order_post = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'order');
    $order = ($order_post['dir'] == 'desc') ? 'ascending' : 'descending';

    // add 1 day in seconds to get records also for end date
    $endTimestamp = strtotime($endDate) + 86410;
    $endDate = date("n/j/Y", $endTimestamp);

    $gs_result = Gs_Api::member_transaction_history($type, $startDate, $endDate, $order, $length, $start);
    $transactions = array();
    if ($type == 'deposit' && isset($gs_result->scriptData) && isset($gs_result->scriptData->deposit)) {
        $transactions = $gs_result->scriptData->deposit;
    } elseif ($type == 'withdrawal' && isset($gs_result->scriptData) && isset($gs_result->scriptData->withdrawal)) {
        $transactions = $gs_result->scriptData->withdrawal;
    }

    $total = (count($transactions) == $length) ? $length + 1 : $length;
    $result['draw'] = $draw;
    $result['iTotalRecords'] = $total;  
    $result['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = $total; 
    $result['data'] = array();
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat ("D F j Y H:i:s", $transaction->time);
        $result_row = array();
        $result_row[] = $date->format('m-d-Y H:i:s'); 
        $result_row[] = $transaction->amount;
        $result_row[] = __('transaction_status_'.$transaction->status, core_plugin::I18N_DOMAIN);
        $result['data'][] = $result_row;
    }

    wp_send_json($result);
}
```

As you can see I want to show the results in a datatable with server-side processing, taking 20 record per call and putting them into a single page.
Every datatable's page can have only 20 records. 
But it messes up. For example: if I have 60 records, the table shows only the first two pages. 
If I try to change iDisplayLength and $length to 10 the datatables should show me 6 pages with 10 records per page but instead it only shows two page with 10 records per page. 
What am I doing wrong?!

UPDATE: the problem seems to be $result['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = $total; 
If I delete it the datatable shows me all of the records but the number of pages is infinite. Since the total number of records is 46 I've tried setting it at 50 and the datatables correctly shows me 3 pages with 20 records per page (and 6 in the last one). But if I set iTotalDisplayRecords = $length it goes in full bug-mode and blocks the pagination to two pages.......

Comment: set lengthChange: true and pageLength: 20 - from https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Comment: lengthChange is used to let user change the number of results per page, so I don't need it. pageLength is the equivalent of iDisplayLength for client-side processing so I don't need it too since I'm using server-side processing. BTW drowning in desperation I've already tried this with no luck

Comment: Some other suggestions that may help you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665865/paging-data-tables-in-jquery

Comment: I see another tip to clear your browser cache after changing iDisplayLength, but i'm sure you already tried this.